# Install Java TimeZone update

Tags: redhat, java, timezone

I need to install a time zone update to java on a RedHat 5.3 server. I researched online and there is a tool called `tzupdater` which does this, but the latest version is 2011n and I need to install patch 2012b.

Does anyone know how to manually install a tzdata file?

Comment: Linux --> distribution?

Comment: running RHEL 5.3

Answer (score 2):

[tzupdater README](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) shows the required version is now available.

It appears that the timezones are installed in the `jre/lib` subdirectory.  Timezone definintions are exploded in the `jre/lib/zi` directory tree.  If you have the correct timezone files you should be able to copy them into place.  I would recommend waiting for the updater files if at all possible.

If you have the JDK installed you may have two jre directory trees.  If you have multiple java versions installed you will have multiple jre directory trees.

Comment: The readme only points to a BUG report stating that patch 2012b _should_ be included with tzupdater, it is not part of it yet. If you try to download it, it downloads version 2011n

Comment: Readme includes the list of bugs that have been implemented.  The latest version has not made it to the download site.  It appears to be only available from Oracle Support.  It was just generated last week, and it may take a while to get to the download site.